# Using the Python gRPC client from a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-multithreading, grpc, concurrent.futures

I would like to speed up some processing by sending out multiple gRPC requests from a Python client, and waiting for the response. It seems like the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` would be a good fit, since this will be mostly IO work. But it seems the gRPC client never releases the GIL and I'm unable to achieve any speedup.

My code goes something like this

```
def do_call():
    return stub.Call(something)

futures = []
thread_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(workers=10)
for _ in range(100):
    futures.append(thread_pool.submit(do_call))

for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    print(future.result())
```

In the end, this goes slower than just calling the method 100 times synchronously. What could I be doing wrong? I've tried using one channel, and creating a separate stub per request, but that didn't change anything.

I know that the stub has a `stub.Call.future()` method, which I could use. My issue is that the `do_call()` function is actually pretty complex, and I want to avoid having to rewrite all the processing to be callbacks on a future.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you solve this ? Could you please share the sample client code. I am a new python coder and want to send multiple gRPC requests out and process the stream replies.

Comment: I think there was something wrong in my set-up when I posted this question. I don't think there is any bug in the code or problem with gRPC. Maybe the server I was sending the requests to did not really handle the concurrent requests well.